# How to get Word.Range.Start/End of each Paragraph in Header in VSTO

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ms-word, vsto

How to get `Word.Range.Start` of Each Paragraph in Header/Footer in VSTO.

If I show

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Range(para.Range.Start, para.Range.Start);
```

It's always showing main document only.

Please help me to get header paragraph start/end range.

```
foreach (Word.Section section in sections)
{
    foreach (Word.HeaderFooter wordFooter in section.Headers)
    {
        foreach (Word.Paragraph para in section.Range.Paragraphs)
        {   
          // Word.Range selectStartRange = para.Range(para.Range.Start, para.Range.Start);
             selectStartRange.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use para.Range instead of wordFooter.Range if you need the header range.

Comment: I have multiple paragraph, so i need to modify specific paragraph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
foreach (Word.Section section in document.Sections)
{
    foreach (Word.HeaderFooter wordFooter in section.Headers)
    {
        foreach (Word.Paragraph para in wordFooter.Range.Paragraphs) // see the change of wordFooter in this line
        {
            Word.Range range = para.Range;

            range.SetRange(1, 5);
            range.Delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want delete full paragraph, if first character something, then i want to delete first character only

Comment: I updated the answer to include selection of a subset of the range. In this case the first 5 characters.

Comment: Hi Patcick, Thanks for quick reply, it's working fine. One more doubt, can i avoid multiple for each loop here, like using linq method

Comment: It's all the same in the end. I don't use linq to much, so maybe you can have a look at other posts at SO.